# Search Videos on Youtube using Youtube API v3 in Android App

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am using the following code for searching videos on youtube and displaying the results. When I run my app, it get closed after sometime with message "Unfortunately, App has stopped."

```
public void SearchButton(View v)
{
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showText);
    AutoCompleteTextView search = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchBox);

    String search_pharse = t.getText().toString();

    youTube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer()
    {
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {}
    }).setApplicationName("App-Name").build();



    try
    {
        query = youTube.search().list("id,snippet");
        query.setKey(DEVELOPER_KEY);
        query.setQ(search_pharse);
        query.setType("video");
        query.setFields("items(id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/description,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
        query.setMaxResults(MAX_RESULTS);

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
    }


    try
    {
        SearchListResponse searchResponse = query.execute();
        List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
        if (searchResultList != null)
        {
            ShowResults(searchResultList.iterator(), search_pharse,t);
        }
    }
    catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e)
    {

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

}

private  void ShowResults(Iterator<SearchResult> iteratorSearchResults, String query, TextView t)
{
    while (iteratorSearchResults.hasNext())
    {

        SearchResult singleVideo = iteratorSearchResults.next();
        ResourceId rId = singleVideo.getId();

        if (rId.getKind().equals("youtube#video"))
        {
            Thumbnail thumbnail = singleVideo.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault();
            String old = t.getText().toString();
            String new_s = "";
            new_s += " Video Id" + rId.getVideoId() + "\n";
            new_s += " Title: " + singleVideo.getSnippet().getTitle() + "\n";
            new_s += " Thumbnail: " + thumbnail.getUrl() + "\n";
            t.setText(old + new_s);
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong in this code and how can I make my app working?

EDIT:

Log Output

```
 12-04 03:53:40.456 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.457 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.473 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.474 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.487 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.489 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.504 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.506 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.520 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.523 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.536 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.538 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.552 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.555 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.569 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.572 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.583 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.585 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.599 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.601 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.615 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.616 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.630 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.632 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.764 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:40.766 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:41.121 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer I/View: Touch down dispatch to android.widget.Button{425041c8 VFED..C. ........ 303,761-464,857 #7f0c0056 app:id/searchButton}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=89.48895, y[0]=24.347412, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=41023429, downTime=41023429, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
12-04 03:53:41.141 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:41.142 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:41.203 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer I/View: Touch up dispatch to android.widget.Button{425041c8 VFED..C. ...P.... 303,761-464,857 #7f0c0056 app:id/searchButton}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=89.48895, y[0]=24.347412, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=41023512, downTime=41023429, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
12-04 03:53:42.595 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/dalvikvm: create interp thread : stack size=128KB
12-04 03:53:42.595 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/dalvikvm: create new thread
12-04 03:53:42.595 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/dalvikvm: new thread created
12-04 03:53:42.596 22084-22309/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/dalvikvm: threadid=18: interp stack at 0x63868000
12-04 03:53:42.596 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/dalvikvm: update thread list
12-04 03:53:42.596 22084-22309/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/dalvikvm: threadid=18: created from interp
12-04 03:53:42.596 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/dalvikvm: start new thread
12-04 03:53:42.596 22084-22309/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/dalvikvm: threadid=18: notify debugger
12-04 03:53:42.596 22084-22309/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/dalvikvm: threadid=18 (OkHttp ConnectionPool): calling run()
12-04 03:53:42.599 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer I/Choreographer: Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-04 03:53:42.623 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:42.624 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:43.144 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:43.147 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:43.637 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:43.638 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:44.141 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:44.142 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:44.630 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:44.632 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:45.135 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:45.137 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:45.641 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:45.643 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:46.147 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:46.150 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:46.652 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:46.654 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:47.163 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:47.165 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:47.663 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:47.664 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:48.185 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:48.194 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:48.671 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:48.673 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:49.179 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:49.181 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:49.664 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:49.665 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:50.189 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:50.191 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:50.701 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:50.705 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:51.177 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:51.186 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:51.681 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:51.682 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:52.185 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:52.193 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:52.691 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:52.692 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:53.204 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:53.208 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:53.713 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:53.714 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:54.217 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:54.219 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:54.705 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:54.707 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:55.217 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:55.219 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:55.711 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:55.712 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:56.225 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:56.226 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:56.726 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:56.728 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:57.233 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:57.234 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:57.737 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:57.738 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:58.236 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:58.237 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:58.748 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:58.750 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:59.253 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:59.255 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:59.759 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:53:59.760 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:00.261 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:00.264 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:00.753 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:00.755 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:01.259 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:01.260 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:01.764 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:01.767 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:02.269 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:02.271 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:02.769 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:02.770 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:03.291 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:03.293 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:03.770 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:03.772 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:04.290 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:04.293 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:04.421 22084-22091/? D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 3999 entries
12-04 03:54:04.422 22084-22091/? D/jdwp: trying to receive file descriptor from ADB
12-04 03:54:04.772 22084-22084/? D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:04.773 22084-22084/? D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:05.276 22084-22084/? D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:05.279 22084-22084/? D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:05.428 22084-22091/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/jdwp: received file descriptor 47 from ADB
12-04 03:54:05.781 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:05.782 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:06.287 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:06.289 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:06.776 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:06.778 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:07.281 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:07.283 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:07.786 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:07.788 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:08.296 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:08.298 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:08.781 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:08.783 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:09.286 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:09.293 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:09.792 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:09.793 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:10.296 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:10.297 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:10.786 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:10.788 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:11.080 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer I/View: Key down dispatch to android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView{425028b0 VFED..CL .F...... 32,682-736,761 #7f0c0055 app:id/searchBox}, event = KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=158, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=41053378, downTime=41053378, deviceId=2, source=0x101 }
12-04 03:54:11.267 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{4248f708 token=android.os.BinderProxy@4248ede0 {com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer.MainActivity}}
12-04 03:54:11.311 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY_FINISHING handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@4248ede0
12-04 03:54:11.316 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: prepareDirty (0.00, 0.00, 768.00, 1280.00) opaque 1 <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:11.317 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: finish <0x623c1908>
12-04 03:54:11.386 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
12-04 03:54:11.386 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x623c1380) (w:768 h:1280 f:1)
12-04 03:54:11.387 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x623571e8) (w:768 h:1280 f:1)
12-04 03:54:11.387 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x62354160) (w:768 h:1280 f:1)
12-04 03:54:11.389 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x6234d5a0) (w:768 h:1280 f:1)
12-04 03:54:11.408 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
12-04 03:54:11.809 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 1)
12-04 03:54:11.811 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
12-04 03:54:11.827 22084-22084/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/ActivityThread: ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@4248ede0
12-04 03:54:42.599 22084-22309/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/dalvikvm: threadid=18: exiting
12-04 03:54:42.599 22084-22309/com.pibytwo.veena.youtubeplayer D/dalvikvm: threadid=18: bye!
```

Comment: Can't really help without the error!

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal - Added the log output.